# Hibernate - ERROR: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, hibernate

I'm using this code to insert data from one table to another,

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.createSQLQuery(
                "INSERT INTO news_statistics (crime_type, crime_district, crime_date, crime_year, crime_yearquarter, crime_count) " +
                        "(SELECT crime_type,(SELECT district FROM location_district_mapper ldm WHERE ceg.location = ldm.location) , crime_date, YEAR (crime_date), CONCAT(YEAR (crime_date), ' - ', QUARTER(crime_date)), count(id) " +
                        "FROM crime_entity_group ceg " +
                        "WHERE crime_date >= '2012-01-01' AND crime_date <= '2014-12-31' " +
                        "GROUP BY crime_type, district, crime_date " +
                        "ORDER BY YEAR ('crime_date'))").executeUpdate();
```

This throws the error,

```
ERROR: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: 'crime_date'
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:389)
    at com.cse10.analyzer.StatGenerator.generateStats(StatGenerator.java:22)
    at com.cse10.analyzer.Analyzer.main(Analyzer.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: 'crime_date'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3556)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2109)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2643)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2362)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2280)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 10 more
```

But when I directly run the query with **phpmyadmin** the query runs well without showing any errors....!

When I run only the `select` part of the query and list results with `list()`, it gives no errors. Because of that I can assume the problem is with the `insert` part of the query. When I remove the `crime_date` from the query, the query runs without showing any errors.

The type of `crime_date` in both tables is `date` and defined in following way in both hibernate `xml` files.

```
<property name="crimeDate" type="date">
        <column name="crime_date" not-null="false"/>
</property>
```

The schemas are,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `crime_entity_group` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `crime_article_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crime_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crime_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `district` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `police` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `court` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `criminal` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `victim` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `victim_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `possession` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news_statistics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `crime_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crime_district` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crime_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `crime_year` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crime_yearquarter` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crime_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Anybody knows a solution?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Try to remove the `(..) ` around your first (outer) `select`. They are useless

Comment: I would suggest simplifying the SQL bit by bit until you find where the issue is. For a start, can you reproduce this with *just* a select, and no insert?

Comment: @JonSkeet.The issue is with insertion of `crime_date`.

Comment: Can you show the ddl of  `news_statistics` and `crime_entity_group`

Comment: @Jens I added the `ddl`s..

Comment: Can you try run the `select` to see the data which will be inseted

Comment: @Jens I'm so sorry... The problem was with `ORDER BY YEAR ('crime_date'))`. It should be changed to `ORDER BY YEAR (crime_date))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with `ORDER BY YEAR ('crime_date'))`. My mistake.. `'crime_date'` is a string, not a date. That's why the error was thrown. It should be changed to `ORDER BY YEAR (crime_date))`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the `news_statistics.crime_date` and the `crime_entity_group.crime_date` are of the same SQL type (e.g. DATE, TIME, TIMESTAMP, DATETIME).

If one is DATE and the other is DATETIME, your statement will fail because of the type mismatch constraint violation.

From your exception message:

> Incorrect datetime value: 'crime_date'

It seems like the `news_statistics.crime_date` is a DATETIME column, while the `crime_entity_group.crime_date` is probably a DATE.

Comment: But why does it say 'incorrect date time value'? It's strange.

Comment: I'm so sorry... The problem was with `ORDER BY YEAR ('crime_date'))`. It should be changed to `ORDER BY YEAR (crime_date))`. My mistake..

Comment: Makes sense now. YEAR doesn't take a VARCHAR. Good question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This expression

```
CONCAT(YEAR (crime_date), ' - ', QUARTER(crime_date))
```

will be evaluated to something like '2015 - 1', and this is not valid value for columns of type DATE or DATETIME. Valid values for MySQL are like **'yyyy-mm-dd'**, and also remove the white spaces arround the ' - ' (dash) sign.

Comment: Thanks. But the column related to this is defined as `varchar`. The problem is with the `crime_date`.